# Lookup function failing on Number attribute

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, lookup

I have a Lookup function that should use ReferenceParameters from the URL to pull information from a DE using the Subscriber Key. However, when that Subscriber Key in the DE is set to a number attribute, the page fails to load. When the exact same functions are changed to a DE where that key is a text attribute, the page loads correctly.

I want to be able to keep the Subscriber Key as a number attribute - so how do I get the function to call to it correctly?

Here's the code - all that I changed between the two was to swap between the Number DE and the Text DE:

```
%%[

var @RP, @ID

IF IsNull(RequestParameter('rp')) THEN
    SET @RP = 9999
ELSE SET @RP = RequestParameter('rp')
ENDIF

IF IsNull(Lookup("Master Info NUMBER","ID","ID", @RP)) THEN
 SET @ID = 9999
ELSE SET @ID = Lookup("Master Info NUMBER","ID","ID", @RP)
ENDIF

]%%
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this series of conditionals.  I don't ever use [isnull()](https://ampscript.guide/isnull).  The [empty()](https://ampscript.guide/empty) function works fine in most cases.

```ampscript
%%[

var @RP, @ID, @debug

set @debug = 1
set @rp = RequestParameter('rp')

if @debug == 1 then
  output(concat("<br>rp (1): ", @rp))
endif

/* set rp to 9999 if empty */
if empty(@rp) then 
  set @rp = 9999
endif

if @debug == 1 then
  output(concat("<br>rp (2): ", @rp))
endif

set @id = Lookup("Master Info NUMBER","ID","ID", @RP)

if @debug == 1 then
  output(concat("<br>id: ", @id))
endif

if empty(@id) then
  raiseerror("id not found",1)
endif

]%%
```

If it works, just set `set @debug = 0` to remove the debugging output.

Comment: That got it to deliver the ID number, thank you! And I'll look into swapping our IsNull functions for Empty ones instead.